# How do I desaturate a BufferedImage in Java?

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

What's the simplest way to desaturate a `BufferedImage`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`ColorConvertOp`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html):

```
public static BufferedImage desaturate(BufferedImage source) {
    ColorConvertOp colorConvert = 
        new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
    colorConvert.filter(source, source);

    return source;
}
```

---

**Update :**
There is indeed a simpler way. You can use the [`GrayFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/GrayFilter.html) class. What's nice about this class is that it provides a static utility method (i.e. `createDisabledImage(Image i)`) that will return a grayed-out version of the image `i`.

That being said, I think the simplest way to desaturate a `BufferedImage` instance is the following:

```
BufferedImage desaturatedImage = GrayFilter.createDisabledImage(originalImage);
```

Comment: Indeed. Is there a simpler way? ;-) i.e. without ConvertColorOp?

Comment: @Dycey That's three lines of code. You can't really get much simpler than that.

Comment: @Dycey Simpler as in call the desaturate() method implemented in this answer?

Comment: @Dycey, I think using `ColorConvertOp`is as simple as it's going to get to perform pixel-by-pixel color conversion. :)